# Charging problems, MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) c

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, big-sur

I have the MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) and I've been having weird charging issues (I recently upgraded to macOS Big Sur if thats relevant). When I connect the charger it won't always charge, and when I press the battery symbol it only says "not charging". One of the ports never works, but the other works after its been plugged in for a little while.
The battery still drains when the charger is connected but not charging.

I've tried resetting SMC, troubleshooting/diagnostic scan shows nothing wrong, the ports and the charger looks undamaged...

The battery works completely fine as far as I know other than this, this is a recent issue.

Comment: Try to install coconut battery (https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) and see what it tells about the battery. Also are you using the original Apple power adapter? You can't charge a MacBook with e.g. a USB-A plug with an USB-A to USB-C adapter since the MacBook draws too much power.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the original USB-C adapter that came with the Macbook!

Idk what the coconut battery things means, but it says stuff like Current charge 3061 mAh, Full charge capacity 4955 mAh, Cycle Count 76, macOS battery status good, charging with 34,04 watts, power adapter 60 watts

Comment: The part *charging with* part is the important one. Try the different configs again (different ports and different wait times) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that you are using the correct charger, and not a lower-rated charger from a different Mac, such as a MacBook Air. If you have another charger, or can borrow one from a friend, it's worth checking whether a different charger works correctly or not. (Or alternatively, see if the charger works ok on another Mac.)

As this is a recent purchase, you should take it to an Apple Store for investigation. I realise that may be difficult at the moment with Covid-19 restrictions. It's likely to be a hardware problem that can't easily be identified or fixed remotely. *(I wait to be proved wrong!)*